# Updating values of objects within array using object method

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I've spent some time looking into this, and while I've seen similar questions none of them have worked for my issue.

My problem is, when I'm updating these objects, only the last one updates correctly. The other one (or more) either don't move at all (debugger shows they're being called, but the update function does nothing even with nonzero inputs), or does move and doesn't collide properly even though the last one exhibits correct behavior. I'm really stuck on trying to figure out how to get them all to update correctly.

What is going on is that I have 3 classes involved. Application, Target, and Point. The main function calls Application.run(), which handles running and keeping track of all the other objects/methods.

So in Application I have an array of Targets, TargetsInScene. I initialize it here:

```
void Application::InitTargets() {
    TargetsInScene = (Target **) malloc(sizeof(Target *)*MaxTargets);
    TargetCount = 0;
    // initialize some static class variables here

    TargetsInScene[TargetCount] = new Target(1);
    TargetCount++;
    TargetsInScene[TargetCount] = new Target(1);
    TargetCount++;
}

Application::Application(int screenX, int screenY) {
    InitTargets();
}
```

and then Application.Run() calls this:

```
void C_Application::UpdateTargets() {
    for (int i = 0; i < TargetCount; i++)
    {
        TargetsInScene[i]->Update();
    }
```

the update function looks like this:

```
void Target::Update() {

   // changes direction if it hits something
   checkCollisions()

   //coord is a Point obj and update +='s the new values to its x and y values
   coord.update(dir*speed, dir*speed);
}
```

Comment: Not sure why you're using arrays instead of `std::vector<Target>`, which would be a much nicer way to handle this. But, I can't see any bugs in your current code as-posted (although you left out a lot of code).

Comment: The `Target` class member variables aren't declared as `static` are they?

Comment: I have also tried vectors with the exact same results. and some of the class variables are static, but the ones I'm trying to  change are not.

Comment: Have you checked TargetCount in UpdateClocks?

Answer (score 0):

Using a vector like this works and is much cleaner and saver.

```
  1 #include <iostream>
  2 #include <vector>
  3 
  4 struct Target {
  5     void update()
  6     {
  7         std::cout << "Updating: " << id << std::endl;
  8      
  9     }
 10     Target(int i) : id(i){};
 11 
 12     int id;
 13 };
 14 
 15 int main()
 16 {
 17     std::vector<Target> TargetsInScene;
 18     for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) { 
 19         TargetsInScene.emplace_back(i);
 20     } 
 21     for (auto& target : TargetsInScene) {
 22         target.update();
 23     }   
 24 }
```